# auto complete extender without webservice

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I was trying to implement auto complete extender in my presentation layer,without using a web service. And I have a code like this.

But,I dont  know where I was going wrong ,but unable to call my web method which is in my code behind  . I have enabled pagemethods to true in my script manager too.

And I dont have updatepanels too.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdata" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtdata"
MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetData" >
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

My Code Behind is

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public List<string> GetData(string prefixText,int count)
{

//my code to get a list from DAL

return list;
}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You say you're not using a web service. Is GetData therefore a method on your page class?

Comment: yes it is a method in my page class.. I am using these namespaces  but still cannot call it [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

Comment: Yuriy's answer below will solve your issue. The ScriptMethodAttribute decorator is extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetData` method must be static. You can find more info here: [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)